# Javascript convert time to epoch format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, epoch

I have a date sting that looks like this `2016-02-21T02:14:39.000000`

would like to convert it to Epoch time using Javascript if possible

Comment: Strictly, date strings without a timezone should be treated as local, is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var ts = "2016-02-21T02:14:39.000000";

var unix_seconds = ((new Date(ts)).getTime()) /1000;

console.log(unix_seconds);
```

`getTime` returns milliseconds, so divide by 1000 to get seconds

https://jsfiddle.net/tbxac0de/

Comment: Except that not all browsers in use support that format and of those that do, some (such as Chrome) erroneously treat it as UTC, so safer to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably by "convert it to Epoch time" you mean a number of seconds or milliseconds since the common UNIX and ECMAScript epoch. The time value can be found by converting the string to a Date and getting its internal time value.

By far the best way to convert a string to a Date is to manually parse it. A library can help, but a function isn't difficult to write. E.g. to parse "2016-02-21T02:14:39.000000" as a local date (i.e. ISO 8601 format without a time zone), use something like:

```js
// Parse y-m-dTh:m:s as local date and time
// since there is no timezone
function parseIsoLocal(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0],b[1]-1,b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5],
                 ((b[6]||'')+'000').slice(0,3));
}

// Convert string to Date
var d = parseIsoLocal('2016-02-21T02:14:39.000000');

// Show date and milliseconds since epoch
document.write(d + '<br>' + +d);
```

The above can easily be extended to treat the string as UTC, incorporate time zones and validate the input, but that doesn't seem to be required in this case.

Note that most browsers will parse the format in the OP, however some in use will not and, of those that will, some treat it as local and some as UTC. According to ISO 8601, it should be treated as local so that's what I've done.